# How can I change the login info for a .mdf sql server file that had windows authentication set, if the computer no longer exists?

Tags: authentication, outlook, mdf

At our company, we had a computer running Outlook 2007 Business Contact Manager, with all our info tied to the SQL Server database MSSmallBusiness.mdf file.  Everything was fine and dandy.  We decided to update the computer to Windows 7, so we upgraded, and Windows 7 put all the old files into the Windows.old folder.

Problem is we reinstalled Outlook Business Contact Manager, and now it tells us we cannot connect to the database because we don't have access to it.  (we changed the name of the PC when upgrading) and it uses windows authentication I guess.

I tried taking the database to my development machine and attaching it to the server there, but we get the same thing, Login Failed, or Access Denied...

What do I do here?  Did we really just lose all our data, even know we have the database file right in front of us?

Answer (score 0):

I totally meant .mdf file, not md5...not sure what I was thinking